# Angular watch getting fired when both old and newvalues are same

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
        function infoboxController($scope) 
{

    $scope.current_view_ =  myGlobalInstance.current_view_;


    $scope.$watch($scope.current_view_, 
            function(newValue, oldValue)
            {       
                console.log(newValue);
                console.log(oldValue);

                console.log($scope.current_view_);

                if($scope.current_view_!=null)
                    $scope.dataset = $scope.current_view_.dataset;  
            }
        );

}
```

console output

```
undefined infobox.js:10
undefined infobox.js:11
null
```

myGlobalInstance is an instance of JS class I have created. Its current_view_ is initially null, but gets set to a value after creation of the instance

Comment: please show more code. Nothing to do with what you posted so far

Comment: That can happen, and you should put the necessary checks in place.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the `$watch` function doesn't automatically fix this, but you are correct.  Your `$watch` callback will be fired whenever the reference to the reference to your `$scope` attribute changes or is updated.  This means that the callback will be fired even if the reference is changed to the same previous value.

To fix this, do the following:

```
$scope.$watch('current_view_', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal != oldVal){  // if values are the same, don't do anything
        // do the rest of your code here, such as:
        $scope.dataset = $scope.current_view_.dataset;
    };
});
```

The watcher callback is still called, but at least it won't do anything when you don't want it to.  The `$watch` callback will still get called *every* time the `$scope.current_view_` reference changes, but this way it won't actually set the `$scope.dataset` value if it simply changes to the same value it was before.  Does that make sense?

Comment: and watch does not get called again when the value actuall changes from null to something of user, how to make it get called again?

Comment: I added a little bit more to my previous answer to hopefully help it make more sense.  Let me know if you're still confused.

Comment: I think $watch doesn't automatically fix this because it wants to give you the flexibility within $watch to decide what to do whenever there's an update.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess it's more flexible this way, I've just never found an instance where I wanted the callback to fire when the value was the same as before.

Comment: Might it be better to use `if(!angular.equals(newVal,oldVal))` ?

Answer (score 1):

When $watch fires, oldValue and newValue are always different with one exception: when the watcher is initialised. So, the very first time the function runs this will be true: `oldValue===newValue`. From AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

Answer (score 0):

$watch does *not* fire the callback unless the value changes ... except for initialization (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).  So, the output shown must be from initialization.  The next time the callback fires, the new value will be something other than undefined.

You didn't really ask a question or describe a problem you are having.  Maybe you were surprised that the old value can equal the new value in a $watch callback.